# Symfony3.1 : Traditional Login Form doesn't work

Tags: authentication, firewall, symfony-3.1

I've folowed the official symfony documentation to create a login form: http://symfony.com/doc/3.1/security/form_login_setup.html

The form login is displayed, but when I try to connect with valid user I have nothing : no errors, no redirection ... the form is displayed again with no message !

This is my security.yml :

```
security:
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: 
           users:
               superman:
                   password: clark
                   roles: ROLE_PRD, ROLE_CAT, ROLE_BATMAN
               batman:
                   password: bruce
                   roles: ROLE_CAT, ROLE_BATMAN
               test:
                   password: test
                   roles: ROLE_CAT, ROLE_BATMAN
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    autre:
        pattern: ^/catalogue/login
        security: false
    main:
        provider: in_memory
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            #default_target_path: /catalogue/admin/
        pattern: ^/catalogue/admin
access_control:
    - { path: ^/catalogue/admin/produit/$, roles: ROLE_BATMAN}
    - { path: ^/catalogue/admin/produit, roles: ROLE_PRD}
    - { path: ^/catalogue/admin/categorie, roles: ROLE_CAT}
```

And this is my controller SecurityController.php :

```
<?php

namespace CatalogueBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{

    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        //return new Response("<html> <body> SecuriteController </body>  </html>");

        return $this->render('securite/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
}
```

Finally the view :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The routing file :

```
login:
  path:     /catalogue/login
  defaults: { _controller: CatalogueBundle:Security:login }
```

It seems like symfony security system is not catching my form data when submitted, I have nothing in log !

Comment: I also folowed the tutorial on a new fresh install of symfony 3.2  and I still have the same problem : the login form is refreshing and seems not to call to security system !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more than only one problem here.
To help you continue your project,

1. I can't see where your are redirecting the user 'on success' (It is in comment in your security.yml.)
   what you can do is to see in the 'dev' navbar if after login if your user is not anonymoys anymore.
2. I think you have a problem in your security.yml
   the url '/catalogue/login' will be binded to your 'autre' firewall, which you didn't precise your form login information.
   <strike>As I don't have more information in your project, maybe you can remove (or comment) your 'autre' firewall and just add in your access control your login route, with anonymous accepted...</strike>

Try with these info to do something and come back if you have difficulties...

[Edit]
maybe you have to move your 'form_login:' section in your 'autre' firewall, don't forget your provider...